# How to use a key with two match criteria in xslt?

Tags: arrays, xml, xslt

I'm trying to match objects with similar Id's that have two other different properties.

My XML file has the following structure:

```
<array>
  <object>
    <property name="AttributeValue">
      <literal type="string">1</literal>
    </property>
    <property name="AttributeName">
      <literal type="string">Is_Active</literal>
    </property>
    <property name="RecordId">
      <literal type="string">1</literal>
    </property>
  </object>
  <object>
    <property name="AttributeValue">
      <literal type="string">Retail</literal>
    </property>
    <property name="AttributeName">
      <literal type="string">Label</literal>
    </property>
    <property name="RecordId">
      <literal type="string">1</literal>
    </property>
  </object>
  <object>
    <property name="AttributeValue">
      <literal type="string">1</literal>
    </property>
    <property name="AttributeName">
      <literal type="string">MBRSH</literal>
    </property>
    <property name="RecordId">
      <literal type="string">1</literal>
    </property>
  </object>
...
</array>
```

I am trying to match all objects with the same RecordId

```
<xsl:key name="value" match="array/object/property[@name='RecordId']/literal[text()] | array/object/property[@name='AttributeName']/literal[text()]" use="array/object/property[@name='AttributeValue']/literal[text()]" />
  
<xsl:template match="array">
      
<xsl:variable name="RecordId" select="./object/property[@name='RecordId']/literal[text()]"/>

        <xsl:for-each select="$RecordId">

          <xsl:variable name="MBRSH" select="key('value', current() | 'MBRSH')" />
            ....      

        </xsl:for-each>    
       
 </xsl:template>
```

I'm just trying to find a combination that works! Please provide me with your insights.

I did another iteration with the MUENCHIAN METHOD, as recommended. However, I'm obtaining always the same values for the key('value', 'parameter')

```
<xsl:key name="value" match="array/object" use="property[@name='AttributeName']/literal[text()]" />
<xsl:key name="id" match="array/object/property[@name='RecordId']/literal[text()]" use="." />
 
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:variable name="RecordId" select="array/object/property[@name='RecordId']/literal[text()]"/>
     <xsl:for-each select="//array/object/property[@name='RecordId']/literal[text()][count(. | key('id',.)[1]) = 1]">
  
       <xsl:variable name="MBRSH" select="key('value','MBRSH')/property[@name='AttributeValue']/literal[text()]" />
         
    <xsl:variable name="Label" select="key('value', 'Label')[.]/property[@name='AttributeValue']/literal[text()]"/>
            
        
          
</xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Any specific language you are using?

Comment: It's below what I used. The language is in the tile (xslt)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "match all objects with the same RecordId". If you want to **group** objects by RecordId, then see: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info. If not, please clarify, add the expected output and state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: the problem is that I don't know all the values of RecordId. I want to match for all values of RecordId

Comment: The xslt grouping in xslt 1.0 (I should have mentioned it) is with key. And that's what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: Please add the expected result to your question.

Comment: Will be : RecordId = 1; MBRSH = 1: Label = Retail | RecordId = 2;  MBRSH = A: Label = Other thing | RecordId = 3 ; MBRSH = W ; Label = Even Other Thing

Answer (score 0):

It's a classic grouping problem, use Muenchian grouping in XSLT 1.0 or (much easier) `xsl:for-each-group` in later versions.

The first thing that's obviously wrong with your code is the key definition:

```
    <xsl:key name="value" match="array/object/property[@name='RecordId']/literal[text()] |
 array/object/property[@name='AttributeName']/literal[text()]"
 use="array/object/property[@name='AttributeValue']/literal[text()]" />
```

Firstly, I don't know why you've included `AttributeName`, that seems unrelated to anything in your stated requirements.

More importantly, the `use` expression is wrong. The `use` expression is evaluated starting from the matched node, i.e. an element named `literal`. So it just wants to be `use="."`.

The expression `select="key('value', current() | 'MBRSH')"` also looks very odd. I can't imagine what that is trying to achieve.

Comment: Just by the structure of the data you should've understand what I am trying to accomplish. There are more records on the data with different RecordId.  I'm trying to obtain the value for the pair (RecordId, AttributeName). That's so obvious!

Comment: Glad you solved it. But I hope you have learned that you will only get help from other people if you find a way of explaining your problem to them.

Comment: You actually helped. Because I didn't know the Muenchian grouping. I'm quite inexperienced with xslt.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer! It took me all day but I got it!

```
<xsl:key name="id" match="property[@name='RecordId']/literal[text()]" use="." />

<xsl:key name="value" match="array/object" use="concat(property[@name='RecordId']/literal[text()], property[@name='AttributeName']/literal[text()])"/>

<xsl:template match="array">

    <xsl:for-each select="//property[@name='RecordId']/literal[text()][count(. | key('id',.)[1]) = 1]">
 
        <xsl:variable name="record" select="key('id', .)"/>

        <xsl:variable name="test" select="key('value', concat(.,'MBRSH'))/property[@name='AttributeValue']/literal[text()]" />  

        <xsl:variable name="test2" select="key('value', concat(.,'Label'))/property[@name='AttributeValue']/literal[text()]" />  

    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```